# How do you format a huge XML file in Java?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have to process a 4GB XML file using Java.

The problem I have is that the XML file is provided unformatted, the content is actually all on one line with no line breaks.

I would like to format the XML file so it has sensible line breaks and indentation, so that if validation fails (I am using JAXB for the parsing), I can easy locate and inspect the problematic section of the XML.

Does anyone know of a framework that can apply some basic XML formatting programmatically in Java?

Comment: You could ask yourself whether or not it makes sense to format a 4 gig XML file programmatically. If validation failures occur just once in a while, I'd just use an external tool like xmllint to format it then, read it back programmatically and then figure out where it went wrong.

Comment: Why can't you format it the same way you would format a small file?

Answer (score 1):

[CkXml](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/javaCkXmlRef.html) will provide you with what you need via the `getXml` method.

```
CkXml xml = new CkXml();
xml.LoadXml("<root><company><name>Chilkat Software, Inc.</name><url>http://www.chilkatsoft.com/</url><phone>630-784-9670</phone></company></root>");
xml.getXml();

// Output looks like this:
// 
// <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
// 
// <root>
//     <company>
//         <name>Chilkat Software, Inc.</name>
//         <url>http://www.chilkatsoft.com/</url>
//         <phone>630-784-9670</phone>
//     </company>
// </root>
```

There is also [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) which is geared at HTML but should work *good enough* for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but what about [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume the XML is well-formed, just not valid.  If you're generating the XML yourself via JAXB you can output human-readable XML when you marshal the objects.  Your [`Marshaller`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html) is required to provide an option for formatted output.  You set the property like this:

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
```

If the document is provided to you (and you're not generating it) perhaps a tool like [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) would be easiest to work with.  It handles large documents and formats/edits XML.  There's a free trial, so if this is a short-term development issue perhaps you can resolve it during the trial period.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a `Transformer`. Something along the lines of the following:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
StreamResult tranformedDoc = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(new Document()); // Insert content here.

transformer.transform(source, transformedDoc);

// Output string to byte array
return transformedDoc.getWriter().toString().getBytes();
```

Given the size of your XML, I don't know if this is going to be a good solution for you but it's a starting point. There are also probably more efficient ways of doing this too so would be open to criticism.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JAXP identity transform, something like this:

```
javax.xml.transform.Source xmlSource = 
    new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(xmlFile);
javax.xml.transform.Result result = 
    new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(System.out);
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory transFact = 
    javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance();
javax.xml.transform.Transformer trans = 
    transFact.newTransformer();
trans.setOutputProperty("indent", "yes")
trans.transform(xmlSource, result);
```

With luck this will be a streamed transformation (it certainly will if the TransformerFactory is Saxon).

You could extend this approach to insert a streamed validation step into the pipeline, avoiding the need to make two passes over the data. If you do this all in Saxon, an added bonus is that the indentation will be schema-sensitive - ensuring that indentation never disturbs schema-validity.

However, although that meets the stated requirement, I'm not sure it's going to achieve the underlying goals. Indentation is done to make the data human readable. Have you considered what tools you will use to display and manually edit a 4GB document? I can't think of any that will do the job, and the usability would be awful. Also a 4Gb document is likely to machine-generated, so if it's invalid you need to fix the program that generated it, not the data itself - it's likely that any errors in the data will be repeated systematically many times over.

Answer (score 0):

setup a sax parser
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html

create your own content handler and assign it to the sax parser:

```
saxParser.getXmlReader().setContentHandler(new MyContentHandler());
```

The ContentHandler provides access to all aspects of the parsing and will enable you to  process the xml in parts if it has distinct sub-parts e.g:

```
<doc>
   <app></app>
   <app></app>
</doc>
```

you could unmarshal one "app" at a time and process it before trying the next one.